# How to implement the feature like "Liquify / Forward Warp Tool" in photoshop using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, photoshop, texture2d

I'm trying to implement that when dragging the circle cursor on the texture, warp the texture like Fitlers/Liquify/Forward Warp Tool in photoshop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwdvr.png)

This is the code what I implemented.

```
public Texture2D backgroundTexture;
 private Color[] backuppixels;
 public void OnMouseDownEvent(MouseDownEvent evt)
 {
        backuppixels = backgroundTexture.GetPixels();
 }
 public void OnMouseMoveEvent(MouseMoveEvent evt)
 {
       //some code
        WarpTexture(currentposition, delta);
 }
 private void WarpTexture(Vector2 textmousepos, Vector2 delta)
 {
     Color[] pixels = backgroundTexture.GetPixels();
      
     for (int y = 0; y < backgroundTexture.height; y++)
     {
         for (int x = 0; x < backgroundTexture.width; x++)
         {
             var distance = (new Vector2(textmousepos.x, textmousepos.y)
                                - new Vector2(x,y)).magnitude;
             if (distance < radius)
             {
                 int index = y * backgroundTexture.width + x;
                 float factor = Mathf.Pow(distance, warpStrength);
                 Vector2 pixelpos = new Vector2(x, y) - delta;
                 int pixelx = Mathf.FloorToInt(pixelpos.x);
                 int pixely = Mathf.FloorToInt(pixelpos.y);
                 pixelx = Mathf.Clamp(pixelx, 0, backgroundTexture.width - 1);
                 pixely = Mathf.Clamp(pixely, 0, backgroundTexture.height - 1);
                 int pxielindex = pixely * backgroundTexture.width + pixelx;
                 pixels[index] = backuppixels[pxielindex];
             }
         }
     }
     backgroundTexture.SetPixels(pixels);
     backgroundTexture.Apply();
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiAoQ.png)
This picture is what I implemented.

First, I found the pixels on the cursor. Second, when dragging set pixel colors using "delta" and "backuppixels".

It works but not warp texture smoothly like in photoshop. I think, the math formula what I used is not perfect. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well for the soft stretching of the texture data you not only have to store information about the initial or previous pixels but about all pixels you touched on the way to you can stretch the texture between where you started and where you are now

Comment: Thanks for reply.
As you see first picture, when dragging the warped pixels are like water that flows.
But second picture it is not same.
Because  I used simple formula. 
Please tell me if you have any idea about it. Regards.

Comment: Photoshop uses n additional falloff => at the center of the cursor you "pull stronger" than at the border. StackOverflow is not really for inventing algorithms and formulas for you .. we help with specific implementation issues - we do not do the entire implementation for you ;) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> note in particular the section `Search and Research`